# integrating an exponential with polynomial as power

Tags: integration

Integrate $e^{x^3}$ for me please!

I had search and saw this relating image, but on integrating I don't understand how true they integration by part is.

Comment: "saw this relating image": hew, can you show us ?

Answer (score 1):

This integral cannot be evaluated in terms of elementary functions. There does exist a solution using the incomplete gamma function, $$\int e^{x^3} \mathrm d x = \frac{x \Gamma (\frac{1}{3}, -x^3)}{3x}+c$$
but I'm guessing this is outside the scope of what you're asking.

Comment: Curious expression; is there a reason you haven't simplified the $-x$?

Comment: @RiccardoSvenRisuleo Ah, I didn't even realise the simplification there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If we consider
$$I_n=\int e^{x^n}\,dx$$ for $n>2$, they all express in terms of the incomplete gamma function. Formally,
$$I_n=-\frac{x \left(-x^n\right)^{-1/n}}{n} \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{n},-x^n\right)$$